# SSL Certificate error : Invalid CA

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, ca

Can someone explain why this site https://whatsmychaincert.com/?www.uts.edu.au gives an error in certificate chain:

> An error occurred when building the chain for this certificate.  The certificate might lack necessary meta-data or its certificate authority might be malfunctioning.  Details:
>
> - The chain contains an untrusted certificate without standard CA issuer information (subject = "C=BM, O=QuoVadis Limited, CN=QuoVadis Global SSL ICA G3"; issuer = "C=BM, O=QuoVadis Limited, CN=QuoVadis Root CA 2 G3"; error code = 20)

But if I test the same thing on other verification sites like: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html & https://www.digicert.com/help/ there are no issues reported ?
Will appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 2):

This site whatsmychaincert is not trusting the root certificate because, as said in the error message, it doesn't know the issuer "C=BM, O=QuoVadis Limited, CN=QuoVadis Root CA 2 G3"

However both other sites know this issuer and say the certificate is valid. When testing with SSL Labs that most people use to check that kind of things, it also says everything is ok ( https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.uts.edu.au ). SSL Labs gives lots of details, including all certificates sent by the web server, then you exactly see the behavior.

Comment: note that `https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.uts.edu.au ` actually tells us that the certificate is self-signed.

Comment: @user27874 that's not what I see, which certificate are you talking about ?

Comment: It says `QuoVadis Root CA 2 G3   Self-signed`  for `Certificate #1: RSA 2048 bits (SHA256withRSA)` > Certification Paths (click here to expand)

Comment: @user27874 That's normal, the root CA is always self-signed, re-read RFC 5246 7.7 for example.

Comment: Thanks for additional information.  I found [RFC 5246 7.4.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#section-7.4.2) talking about this. (No section 7.7, but that doesn't matter have the information I needed.